# Cannot convert value of type 'Query' to expected condition type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

In my app, I am trying to create a feature where if a users UID is found in a document's array "likedBy", it sets the variable "isLiked" to true. I have a function called "checkForLikes" that is linked to my viewsheet.

So, my goal of my project is to set 'isLiked' to true if the logged in users UID ("uid") is found in the document's array.

However, in the function, I am getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Query' to expected condition type 'Bool'"

*PostViewModel.swift*

```
func checkForLikes(id: String){
        var doc = ref.collection("Posts")
        
        if doc.whereField("likedBy", arrayContains: uid){ /// error is here

            print("Found") /// temporary, eventually to be replaced with setting isLiked = true
        }
}
```

*PostRow.swift*

```
@State private var isLiked = false
```

```
HStack {
                Button(action: {if isLiked == false{
                    postData.addLike(id: post.id)
                    isLiked = true
                } else{
                    postData.unLike(id: post.id)
                    isLiked = false
                }}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
                }).onAppear(perform: {isLiked = postData.checkForLikes(id: post.id)})
            
                
                Text("\(post.likes)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                
            }
            
        }
```

I *believe* I am on the right track with what I have, except I am facing that error. If I am on the wrong track, please let me know because this is my first time doing something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my friend, Ive been able to figure this out.

**PostViewModel.swift*

```
    @State private var isLiked: Bool = false
    @State private var isDisabled: Bool = true
```

```
 func checkForLikes(id: String, then completion: @escaping (Bool?) -> ()) {
        let collection = ref.collection("Posts")
        let doc = collection.document(id)
        
        doc.getDocument { docSnapshot, err in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot,
                  let likedBy = docSnapshot.data()?["likedBy"] as? [String] else {
                print("No query snapshot")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            completion(likedBy.contains(self.uid))
        }
    }
```

*PostView.swift*

```
HStack {
                        Button {
                            if isLiked == false {
                                postData.addLike(id: post.id)
                                isLiked = true
                            } else {
                                postData.unLike(id: post.id)
                                isLiked = false
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
                        }
                        .disabled(isDisabled)
                        .opacity(isDisabled ? 0.3 : 1)
                        .onAppear {
                            postData.checkForLikes(id: post.id) { isLiked in
                                if let isLiked = isLiked {
                                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                                        isDisabled = false
                                        self.isLiked = isLiked
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, `whereField` returns a `Query`. In order to do something with that query, you'll need to call something like `getDocuments` on it to get a result:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").whereField("likedBy", arrayContains: uid).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
    if error != nil {
        //handle error
        return
    }
    if snapshot?.documents.count != 0 {
        //it has likes
    }
}
```